# Update a column with another column value

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns called `id`,`firstTime` and `lastTime`. Each `id` occurs in the table multiple times. I want to find minimum value of `lastTime` for each id and update `firstTime` column of all rows which are belonged to that `id`.

I get minimum lastTime value for each id like this but I couldn't write to update firstTime column. How can I update rows for each id?

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,MIN(lastTime)
FROM logs
GROUP BY id
```

Rows look like this:

```
   id  firstTime  lastTime
   A1   NULL      2015-07-10 11:29:00
   A1   NULL      2015-07-10 20:21:00
   B2   NULL      2015-07-10 11:29:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
UPDATE logs l1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.id
        ,MIN(l.lastTime) AS ltime
    FROM logs l
    GROUP BY l.id
    ) t ON l1.id = t.id

SET l1.firstTime = t.ltime;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3358b/1/0)

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that we can write INNER JOIN before update statement

Comment: The syntax is a little different in MySQL. :)

Answer (score -1):

```sql
UPDATE logs logs1
   SET firstTime = (SELECT MIN(lastTime)
                      FROM logs logs2
                     WHERE logs2.id = logs1.id)
```

Comment: Can you explain to the OP (and others) what's going on here and why this works, just an answer codeblock on its own is relatively worthless. cheers